# Trying to push_back into a vector pointing to an abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11

Compiling my code that contains this class:

```
class Dessin
{
    private:
        vector<Figures*>T;
    public:
        void ajouteFigure(const Figures& f) const
        {
            for(auto element: T)
            {
                T.push_back(f);
            }
        }
};
```

yields an error:

> [Error] no matching function for call to
>   'std::vector::push_back(const Figures&) const'

This is what I'm supposed to do in the main()

```
Dessin s;
s.ajouteFigure(Cercle(1.1));
```

Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: @AlexD Though flawed from the bone.

Comment: Don't store raw pointers in a `std::vector` - use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Figure>>` instead.

Comment: @AlexD I've tried that, it doesn't work. Same error

Comment: @AlexD This works, thanks. May I know why exactly?

Comment: This code is so broken no answer could help you.

Comment: @Amine _"This works"_ I seriously doubt that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree, it doesn't work as it meant to. The code compiles correctly but no element is added to the vector.

Comment: @AlexD Your answers seem to be the correct ones, I just figured out I had to remove the loop. It works fine now.

Comment: @Amine http://stackoverflow.com/a/40065296/3246555 is much better :).

Comment: @AlexD "krzaq" answer is also working fine, but I'm trying to avoid smart pointers as i haven't understood them yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `Cercle` is a class name, you're trying to push a value where a pointer is expected.

To "fix" the error you should change your `ajouteFigure` prototype to accept `Figures` pointers and non-const `this`:

```
void ajouteFigure(Figures* f)
```

Then you should call it passing a pointer to a `Figures` object, i.e. created with a `new` expression:

```
s.ajouteFigure(new Cercle(1.1));
```

That being said, this code seems pointless. You're adding the pointer as many times as you have elements in the vector (which is always 0 in the example you provided).

Using raw pointers is also unadvised, you should use smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), although that would break the current code.

Consider this, less improper, example:

```
class Dessin
{
    private:
        vector<unique_ptr<Figures>> T;
    public:
        void ajouteFigure(unique_ptr<Figures> f)
        {
            T.push_back(move(f)); // just once
        }
};
```

and at the call site:

```
Dessin s;
s.ajouteFigure(make_unique<Cercle>(1.1)); // C++≥14
```

or, if you can't use C++14:

```
Dessin s;
s.ajouteFigure(unique_ptr<Figures>(new Cercle{1.1}));
```

Comment: This question is marked as c++11, you should probably provide an alternative to `std::make_unique` just in case the OP isn't using c++14 yet.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury added.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, I think you would be better to make it a template function and create the right object inside the function with arguments to the constructor passed as function parameters.

This way you don't have to create a `std::unique_ptr` or use `new` every time you call the function.

Here's a basic implementation:

```
class Dessin{
    public:
        template<typename T, typename ... Args>
        void ajouteFigure(Args &&... args){
            figures.emplace_back(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }

    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Figures>> figures;
};
```

Then using the class is less error-prone:

```
int main(){
    Dessin d;
    d.ajouteFigure<Cercle>(1.1);
}
```